# Monitors used for Recording IRs for Small Objects. 

Tags: impulse-response, small

I know you can record IRs with transient sounds but since recording the sine sweeps is the best way to go about I was wondering if playing the sine sweep through small computer monitors work in case I am recording IR for a wine bottle or a tin can etc.? Or do I need to have a professional set of monitors to play it? Will the choice of monitors have an effect on the final IR? I haven't recorded IRs before and I am planning to record a few soon. So wanted to be sure before I started. 
Thank You.

Comment: I believe a majority of smaller object based IRs are created without sweeps, simply by striking the object and using the hit as an IR. I imagine a smaller speaker will impart a bit of a pinched sound on the results, but I'd be curious to hear about your results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the choice of speaker will definitely have an impact on the resulting IR. You can think of your speaker as a filter in the signal chain; all irregularities in the frequency response of the speaker will be present in the final IR as well. Distortion will complicate the matter even more. That's why Altiverb has different import settings depending on what speaker or slate you used to record the sweep or impulse -- they analyzed sweeps/impulses from those sources and are therefore able to compensate.

That, however, doesn't mean that you can't get awesome results with less than stellar speakers. It just means that the IR will not be a faithful representation of the space (unless you compensate for it, as Altiverb does).